# Securing micro-service spring cloud security Oauth2

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-boot, microservices

I am using Spring cloud security and Oauth2 to secure my micro- service. Now the Pom is as follows:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.oreilly.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-microservices-oauth-server</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>spring-microservices-oauth-server</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Dalston.SR3</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

The Spring-boot main class is as below:

```
package com.oreilly.cloud;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@EnableResourceServer
@RestController
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class SpringMicroservicesOauthServerApplication {

    @RequestMapping("/resource/endpoint")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public String endpoint(){
        return "This message is protected by the resource server.";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringMicroservicesOauthServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The authorization server configuration is as follows:

```
package com.oreilly.cloud;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("webapp").secret("websecret").authorizedGrantTypes("password")
                .scopes("read,write,trust");
    }

}
```

**Note the Authentication manager is auto wired into the Authorization config**

In the below class The Authentication Manager is configured and returned as abean so that it can be autowired to the above class:

```
package com.oreilly.cloud;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user1").password("password1").roles("USER").and().withUser("admin")
                .password("password2").roles("ADMIN");
    }

}
```

Now the application.properties is as below:

```
server.port=9090
```

Now i run the Spring boot application as below:

mvn spring-boot:run

The application starts successfully and is ready to accept request on port 9090 on localhost

Now using postman i am sending a post request to get the access_token. A little background is that the Aoauth2 flow being used here is the password grant. So in the AuthorizationServerConfig class above i have defined a password grant flow and registered a simple web app with client name and secret. As can be seen the client configuration is in memory.

The post man request to get access token from authorization server is as follows: Its post request, with Basic auth header header having the 
username as webapp and password as websecret.

http://localhost:9090/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=user1&password=password1

This request returns successfully with a access token json as follows:

```
{
    "access_token": "2d632e54-17c3-41f7-af3b-935ca3022d78",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 43199,
    "scope": "read,write,trust"
}
```

Now when i try to access the /resourse/endpoint with the above access token as follows:

http://localhost:9090/resource/endpoint?access_token=2d632e54-17c3-41f7-af3b-935ca3022d78

Rather than returning the text which is returned from the service /resourse/endpoint it returns the login page as below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login Page</title>
    </head>
    <body onload='document.f.username.focus();'>
        <h3>Login with Username and Password</h3>
        <form name='f' action='/login' method='POST'>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>User:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='text' name='username' value=''>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='password' name='password'/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan='2'>
                        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <input name="_csrf" type="hidden" value="8dbc1c38-6f89-43c5-a8f8-797c920722a1" />
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone please help what i am missing here?????.

**NOTE** I have both authorization server and resourse server configured in same application. this is a POC so i am trying out the Spring-cloud security, later i will separate the two ...but thats for later.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: In your token the value of expires_in looks interesting ..What does it maps to , is is certainly not ticks , can you check that .?

Comment: @WilliamHampshire My Question is i get the access token successfully by hitting the Following URL: http://localhost:9090/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=admin&password=password2 with basic auth header specifying the client username and password but, if i try to access the protected resource (/resource/endpoint/) with the access_token parameter set to the above access token, i am getting a login page rather than the text response which my endpoint is supposed to return

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue by looking through Spring Boot's root debug logs.

If you're using `yml`:

```
src/main/resources/application.yml
----------------------------------
logging:
  level:
    root: DEBUG
```

Or if `properties`:

```
src/main/resources/application.properties
----------------------------------
logging.level.root=DEBUG
```

I realized I was not passing in any user auth info with the `GET`:

```
o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter: Access is denied (user is anonymous); ...
```

So you can do 1 of 2 things:

## 1. Add creds through url params eg.

```
curl -X GET \
  'http://localhost:9090/resource/endpoint?
  username=user1&password=password1&access_token=xxxx'
```

or

## 2. Add creds through basic auth eg.

```
curl -X GET \
  'http://localhost:9090/resource/endpoint?username=user1' \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Did you get this off the **Building Microservices With Spring** course on safaribooksonline, too? :)

I discovered why the teacher wasn't having the issue. He must have authorized the username/password previously -- it seems to get cached somewhere because after you `GET` the resource once, if you call it again with only the `auth_token`, it works.